# Flask cannot get JSON from some type of curl

Tags: curl, flask

My Flask api server can get json from some curl, but cannot get it from other version curl.

I mean,

`content = request.get_json()`

properly work on some curl request, 
but `content` is `None` when receive request from some curl,
even if curl command is exactly the same.

This curl's request is received properly.

```
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.0) libcurl/7.54.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.8
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets
```

And, this curl's request is received IMPROPERLY.

```
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.0.20 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

Does anyone know about this problem?

Comment: Mm could you provide the curl command you are attempting? At first sight, it seems that the one that doesn't work is being encoded (https?) and you are using your local dev server, which is not set up for receiving https requests.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Curl command is here.

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "x-api-key:myapikey" https://myapi/fuga -d '{"text":"I have a pen"}'`

I deployed this API on AWS Lambda with zappa and I try to request by https.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with cURL version 7.54.0, which appears to be installed on macOS by default.

I was able to overcome this exact issue by:

- using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
- then running, `brew install curl`
- along with the required path update as seen during the install output or with `brew info curl`.
- Reload your shell, and you should have the latest version of cURL.

As of this comment was 7.64.0. You can view your installed version with the command `curl -V`.